# Using concurrentHashMap vs Hashmap

Tags: java, multithreading

```
 private static final Map<String, SampleClass> map = new
 ConcurrentHashMap<>();

 public static SampleClass getsampleclass(String context) {

     if( map.get(context) != null) {
         return map.get(context);
     } else {
         SampleClass cls = new SampleClass(context);
         map.put(context, cls);
     }
 }
```

In multi-threaded environment, if two threads get `map.get(context)` as **null**, then both the threads will create `cls`, and put will blocked, therefore `thread1` will put first and after it `thread2` will override what was put by `thread1`.
Is this behavior correct ?
In my case, I want same value to be returned when map.get is done, hence i see using `HashMap` and *synchronizing* it is preferred.

Answer (score 9):

Use CHM's atomic [`computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) method and you won't have to worry about synchronization:

```
return map.computeIfAbsent(context, SampleClass::new);
```

Comment: agreed .. this is the way to move

Comment: @Geeta Reads don't generally need to block with CHM.

Comment: it does block in java8 https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161372